# How to find url of docker-in-docker running in gitlab

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment, docker-in-docker

I have a new application (*https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension/-/tree/5-implement-glue-code* where I am currently working off of branch **5-implement-glue-code** ) that is running in docker (for now, it will eventually run in knative).  The application builds (both locally and on the gitlab ci/cd server), and deploys a docker image (both locally and on gitlab ci/cd server).  It also passes acceptance tests locally.  However, when it runs the acceptance tests on the gitlab ci/cd server, it appears the docker deployment is not exposed/taking place on another host/url.....?

If you wish to run this locally, you can easily do this with a single command (after cloning/cd to the repo): `docker run -i --rm -p 8080:8080 registry.gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension & ./wait-for-it-2.sh`).  If not, you can recreate by cd to the repo and running `./build-it.sh`

Here is an output of the failing build on the gitlab server (when running the command mentioned above `docker run -i --rm -p 8080:8080 registry.gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension & ./wait-for-it-2.sh`).  You can find this output here: https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension/-/jobs/714867229

```
_  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______ 
--/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/ 
-/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \   
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/   
2020-09-01 22:25:39,509 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl    1.0.0-SNAPSHOT native (powered by Quarkus 1.7.0.Final) started in 0.015s. Listening on:    http://0.0.0.0:8080
2020-09-01 22:25:39,509 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated.
2020-09-01 22:25:39,510 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation]
Made request to readiness endpoint (0.0.0.0:8080/health/readiness) and received status code of 000
*   Trying 0.0.0.0...
* TCP_NODELAY set
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* connect to     0.0.0.0 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8080: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
```

As mentioned above, it works locally.  Here is the output when running locally (using the same command)

```
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/ 
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \   
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/   
2020-09-01 23:06:31,525 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT native (powered by Quarkus 1.7.0.Final) started in 0.013s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
2020-09-01 23:06:31,526 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated. 
2020-09-01 23:06:31,526 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation]
//tons of debug logs ommitted for brevity, but you can easily recreate them locally
2020-09-01 23:06:32,112 INFO  [com.con.rea.fil.ContainerResponseFilterLoggingImpl] (executor-thread-1) Request received Request method GETRequest headers Accept: */*
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0Request cookies Query parameters Request url http://0.0.0.0:8080//health/readiness with responseResponse body class                                                                  ReadinessHealthResponse {
  isAvailable: true
  availableDependencies: [class DownstreamDependency {
      name: SystemPropertyChecker
      isAvailable: true
   }, class DownstreamDependency {
    name: MemoryChecker
    isAvailable: true
}]
unavailableDependencies: []
}

Response headers Content-Type: application/jsonResponse status code 200

Made request to readiness endpoint (0.0.0.0:8080/health/readiness) and received status code of 200
*   Trying 0.0.0.0...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /health/readiness HTTP/1.1
> Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
```

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml (found at: *https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension/-/blob/5-implement-glue-code/.gitlab-ci.yml*)

```
image: connorbutch/gradle-and-java-11:latest

variables:
  GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
  DOCKER_DRIVER: "overlay2"

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle

#By running this as the same service for all build pods, I hope to save an extra docker build
services:
  - docker:stable-dind

stages:
  - build
  - docker_build
  - acceptance_test

unit_test:
  stage: build
  script: ./gradlew check
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew clean quarkusBuild
    - ./gradlew clean build -Dquarkus.package.type=native -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true 
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    policy: push
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl/build/

docker_build:
  stage: docker_build
  script:
    - cd reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl
    - docker build -f infrastructure/Dockerfile -t registry.gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension .
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension

acceptance_test:
  stage: acceptance_test
  script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker run -i --rm -p 8080:8080 registry.gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension & ./wait-for-it-2.sh
    - gradle acceptanceTest
```

The output of *docker ps* within the gitlab server seems to show what I expect (given below):

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                    NAMES
d607ecf87991        registry.gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension   "./application -Dqua…"   4 seconds ago       Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   reading-comprehension
```

Relevant excerps from docker inspect (on the container running on the gitlab ci server) are given below:

```
 "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 207,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2020-09-02T00:31:35.621438213Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },

  "NetworkMode": "default",
        "PortBindings": {
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        },

"NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "c18baeec94cb531865994db3184d37949e4c3c34064373ac5d31c49b9eec1d25",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/c18baeec94cb",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "246efed470908aede697bce92f55fb5f58885634eb06ecdbe90686d2beddd41b",
        "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "d543b622c078986bab878111bb8bbdfe70f4b60fb384c5a7a175295c13ae9d68",
                "EndpointID": "246efed470908aede697bce92f55fb5f58885634eb06ecdbe90686d2beddd41b",
                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    }
```

My suspicion is that the docker in docker service running in gitlab ci server is running on another host, or not setup to handle traffic.  Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this?

Thanks,
Connor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try using docker:8080 to connect instead of localhost. I am not totally sure but I think I had this issue with dind. In this situation, your service is not exposed to the host but to dind service. Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks so much Cyril!  This worked.  Now I have a database I am using as well, do you happen to know the url of docker-compose running in gitlab ci?